# Get date from timestamp SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which is storing dates as Unix timestamps ( i.e 1369763646)

To get data of a specific date I have to retrieve first all data in array and then loop using the PHP date function to separate specific date results.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$collect = array();
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d",$row['date']);
     if($date == $today)
      $collect[] = $row;
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve data only of a specific date from timestamp without getting all data into array with a single query like..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '28-05-2013';
```

Comment: why not converting your date to timestamp?

Comment: I have to change a lot of code if i convert it in mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = '2013-05-28';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `from_unixtime()` in your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), ' ', 1) = '28-05-2013'
```

This will convert your date field from a timestamp to a date format (28-05-2013 22:13:02). `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`will then retrieve the first part of the date field (28-05-2013), and you can just use a standard WHERE clause for the next part :)

Comment: I was about to write the same answer though you are faster :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not exactly what you're asking, you can do a

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,5,28,2013);
```

to get your desired date as a timestamp and run the query with that

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
$start = strtotime( '2013-05-28 00:00:00' );
$end   = strtotiem( '2013-05-28 23:59:59' );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN {$start} and {$end}";
```

`from_unixtime` might be better, but this leaves the timestamp calculation to PHP, which i tend to prefer as that can slow down your query